# Xtext : identify when a optional must be call

Tags: modeling, xtext, emf

I am using xtext to define a grammar.
I have a problem with the runtime syntax evaluation.

the  rule is signatureDeclaration. Here the full grammar:

```
// automatically generated by Xtext
grammar org.xtext.alloy.Alloy with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

import "http://fr.cuauh.als/1.0" 
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

//specification ::= [module] open* paragraph* 
//ok
Specification returns Specification:
    {Specification}
    (module=Module)?
    (opens+=Library (opens+=Library)*)?
    (paragraphs+=Paragraph (paragraphs+=Paragraph)*)?;

//module ::= "module" name  [ "["  ["exactly"] name  ("," ["exactly"] num)*    "]" ]
//module ::= "module" name?  [ "["  ["exactly"] name  ("," ExactlyNum )* "]" ]
//ok
Module returns Module:
    {Module}
    'module' (name=IDName)? ('['(exactly?='exactly')? extensionName=[IDref] (nums+=ExactlyNums ( "," nums+=ExactlyNums)*)?']')?
    ;

IDName returns IDName:
    name=ID
;
terminal ID         : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9'|'/')*;
//open ::= ["private"]  "open"  name  [ "[" ref,+ "]" ]  [ "as" name ]
//open ::= ["private"]  "open"  path  [ "[" ref,+ "]" ]  [ "as" name ]
//ok
Library returns Library:
    {Library}
    (private?='private')? 'open' path=EString ('['references+=Reference (',' references+=Reference)*']')? ('as' alias=Alias)? 
    ;
//a path 
//ok
//terminal PATH returns ecore::EString :
//  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'.')+('/'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'.')+)*
//;

//paragraph ::= factDecl | assertDecl | funDecl | cmdDecl | enumDecl | sigDecl
//paragraph ::= factDecl | assertDecl | funDecl | predDecl | cmdDecl | enumDecl | sigDecl
//ok
Paragraph returns Paragraph:
    FactDeclaration | AssertDeclaration | FunctionDeclaration | PredicatDeclaration | CmdDeclaration | EnumerationDeclaration | SignatureDeclaration;

//cmdDecl ::= [name ":"] ("run"|"check") (name|block) scope
//cmdDecl ::= [name ":"] command (ref|block) scope ["expect (0|1)"]
//ok
CmdDeclaration returns CmdDeclaration:
    (name=IDName ':')? operation=cmdOp referenceOrBlock=ReferenceOrBlock (scope=Scope)? (expect?='expect' expectValue=EInt)?;

//ok
ReferenceOrBlock returns ReferenceOrBlock:
    BlockExpr | ReferenceName;  

//sigDecl ::= sigQual* "sig" name,+ [sigExt] "{" decl,* "}" [block]
//sigDecl ::= ["private"] ["abstract"] [quant] "sig" name [sigExt] "{" relDecl,* "}" [block]
//ok
SignatureDeclaration returns SignatureDeclaration:
    {SignatureDeclaration}
    (isPrivate?='private')? (isAbstract?='abstract')? (quantifier=SignatureQuantifier)? 'sig' name=IDName (extension=SignatureExtension)? '{'
    (relations+=RelationDeclaration ( ',' =>relations+=RelationDeclaration)* )? 
    '}'
    (block=Block)?;

//ok
SignatureExtension returns SignatureExtension:
    SignatureinInheritance | SignatureInclusion;


TypeScopeTarget returns TypeScopeTarget:
    Int0 | Seq | ReferenceName;

//name ::= ("this" | ID) ["/" ID]*
//ok do not need to be part of the concrete syntax
//Name returns Name:
//  thisOrId=ThisOrID ('/'ids+=ID0( "/" ids+=ID0)*)?;

//ok do not need to be part of the concrete syntax
//ThisOrID returns ThisOrID:
//  ID0 | This;

EBoolean returns ecore::EBoolean:
    'true' | 'false';

//["exactly"] num
//ok
ExactlyNums returns ExactlyNums:
    exactly?='exactly' num=Number;

//ok do not need to be part of the concrete syntax
//  IDName | IDref;

IDref returns IDref:
    namedElement=[IDName]
;


This returns This:
    {This}
    'this'
    ;

EString returns ecore::EString:
    STRING | ID;

//ok
EInt returns ecore::EInt:
    '-'? INT;

Alias returns Alias:
    {Alias}
    name=IDName;



//factDecl ::= "fact" [name] block
//ok
FactDeclaration returns FactDeclaration:
    'fact' (name=IDName)? block=Block;

//assertDecl ::= "assert" [name] block
//ok
AssertDeclaration returns AssertDeclaration:
    'assert' (name=IDName)? block=Block ;

//funDecl ::= ["private"] "fun" [ref "."] name "(" decl,* ")" ":" expr block
//funDecl ::= ["private"] "fun" [ref "."] name "[" decl,* "]" ":" expr block
//funDecl ::= ["private"] "fun" [ref "."] name                ":" expr block
//
//funDecl ::= ["private"] "fun" [ref "."] name ["(" paramDecl,* ")" | "[" paramDecl,* "]" ] ":" expr block
//ok
FunctionDeclaration returns FunctionDeclaration:
    (private?='private')? 'fun' (reference=[Reference] ".")?    name=IDName
        ('(' (parameters+=ParameterDeclaration ( "," parameters+=ParameterDeclaration)*)? ')'|
         '[' (parameters+=ParameterDeclaration ( "," parameters+=ParameterDeclaration)*)? ']')?
        ':' ^returns=Expression
        block=Block;

//funDecl ::= ["private"] "pred" [ref "."] name "(" decl,* ")" block
//funDecl ::= ["private"] "pred" [ref "."] name "[" decl,* "]" block
//funDecl ::= ["private"] "pred" [ref "."] name                block
//
//predDecl ::= ["private"] "pred" [ref "."] name ["(" paramDecl,* ")" | "[" paramDecl,* "]" ] ":" block
//ok
PredicatDeclaration returns PredicatDeclaration:
    (private?='private')? 'pred' (reference=[Reference|EString] ".")? name=IDName
        ('(' (parameters+=ParameterDeclaration ( "," parameters+=ParameterDeclaration)*)? ')'|
         '[' (parameters+=ParameterDeclaration ( "," parameters+=ParameterDeclaration)*)? ']')?
        block=Block;


//enumDecl ::= "enum" name "{" name  ("," name)*  "}"
//enumDecl ::= "enum" name "{" enumEl  ("," enumEl)*  "}"
//ok
EnumerationDeclaration returns EnumerationDeclaration:
    'enum' name=IDName '{' enumeration+=EnumerationElement ( "," enumeration+=EnumerationElement)* '}';


//ok
EnumerationElement returns EnumerationElement:
    {EnumerationElement}
    name=IDName;

//"lone" | "one" | "some" 
//ok
enum SignatureQuantifier returns SignatureQuantifier:
    lone = 'lone' | one = 'one' | some = 'some';


//decl ::= ["private"] ["disj"] name,+ ":" ["disj"] expr
//decl ::= ["private"] ["disj"] name,+ ":" ["disj"] expr
//ok
RelationDeclaration returns RelationDeclaration:
    (isPrivate?='private')? (varsAreDisjoint?='disj')? names+=VarDecl (',' names+=VarDecl)* ':' (expressionIsDisjoint?='disj')? expression=Expression;

//sigExt ::= "extends" ref
//ok
SignatureinInheritance returns SignatureinInheritance:
    'extends' extends=Reference;
//sigExt ::= "in" ref ["+" ref]*
//ok
SignatureInclusion returns SignatureInclusion:
    'in' includes+=Reference ( "+" includes+=Reference)* ;

//ok
VarDecl returns VarDecl:
    {VarDecl}
    name=IDName;

//decl ::= ["private"] ["disj"] name,+ ":" ["disj"] expr
//ok
ParameterDeclaration returns ParameterDeclaration:
    (isPrivate?='private')? (varsAreDisjoint?='disj')? names+=VarDecl ( "," names+=VarDecl)* ':' (expressionIsDisjoint?='disj')? expression=Expression;

//("run"|"check")
//ok
enum cmdOp returns cmdOp:
    run = 'run' | check = 'check';


//expr ::= 
//1)          "let" letDecl,+ blockOrBar
//2)        | quant decl,+    blockOrBar
//3)        | unOp expr
//4)        | expr binOp   expr
//5)        | expr arrowOp expr
//6)        | expr ["!"|"not"] compareOp expr
//7)        | expr ("=>"|"implies") expr "else" expr
//8)        | expr "[" expr,* "]"
//9)        |     number
//10)       | "-" number
//11)       | "none"
//12)       | "iden"
//13)       | "univ"
//14)       | "Int"
//15)       | "seq/Int"
//16)       | "(" expr ")"
//17)       | ["@"] Name
//18)       | block
//19)       | "{" decl,+ blockOrBar "}" 

//  expr ::= leftPart [rightPart]
Expression returns Expression:
    lhs=NonLeftRecursiveExpression (=>parts=NaryPart)?;     

//4)        | expr binOp   expr
//5)        | expr arrowOp expr
//6)        | expr ["!"|"not"] compareOp expr
//7)        | expr ("=>"|"implies") expr "else" expr
//8)        | expr "[" expr,* "]"
//ok
NaryPart returns NaryPart:
    BinaryOrElsePart | CallPart;

//4)        | expr binOp   expr
//5)        | expr arrowOp expr
//6)        | expr ["!"|"not"] compareOp expr
//7)        | expr ("=>"|"implies") expr "else" expr
//
//7)        | expr ("=>"|"implies") expr "else" expr
//4)5)6)    | expr binaryOperator expr*
//ok
BinaryOrElsePart returns BinaryOrElsePart:
    =>('=>'|'implies') rhs=Expression (=>'else' else=Expression)? |
    operator=BinaryOperator rhs=Expression ;

//8)        | expr "[" expr,* "]"
//it is just the right part
//ok
CallPart returns CallPart:
    {CallPart}
    '['(params+=Expression ( "," params+=Expression)*)?']';


//1)          "let" letDecl,+ blockOrBar
//2)        | quant decl,+    blockOrBar
//19)       | "{" decl,+ blockOrBar "}" 
//18)       | block
//          | terminalExpression
NonLeftRecursiveExpression returns NonLeftRecursiveExpression:
    LetExpression | QuantifiedExpression | CurlyBracketsExpression | BlockExpr | TerminalExpression;

//1)          "let" letDecl,+ blockOrBar
//ok
LetExpression returns LetExpression:
    'let' letDeclarations+=LetDeclaration ( "," letDeclarations+=LetDeclaration)* blockOrBar=BlockOrBar;

//2)        | quant decl,+    blockOrBar
//ok
QuantifiedExpression returns QuantifiedExpression:
    quantifier=QuantifiedExpressionQuantifier varDeclaration+=VarDeclaration ( "," varDeclaration+=VarDeclaration)* blockOrBar=BlockOrBar;

//
//binOp ::= "||" | "or" | "&&" | "and" | "&" | "<=>" | "iff" | "=>" | "implies" | "+" | "-" | "++" | "<:" | ":>" | "." | "<<" | ">>" | ">>>"
//compareOp ::= "=" | "in" | "<" | ">" | "=<" | ">="
//arrowOp ::= ["some"|"one"|"lone"|"set"] "->" ["some"|"one"|"lone"|"set"]
//ok
BinaryOperator returns BinaryOperator:
    RelationalOperator | CompareOperator | ArrowOperator;

//ok
RelationalOperator returns RelationalOperator:
    operator=RelationalOp;

//binOp ::= "||" | "or" | "&&" | "and" | "&" | "<=>" | "iff" | "=>" | "implies" | "+" | "-" | "++" | "<:" | ":>" | "." | "<<" | ">>" | ">>>"
//ok
enum RelationalOp returns RelationalOp:
                or = '||' | and = '&&' | union = '+' | intersection = '&' | difference = '-' | equivalence = '<=>' | override = '++' 
                | domain = '<:' | range = ':>' | join = '.' ; // | lshift = '<<' | rshift = '>>' | rrshift = '>>>'; 

//["!"|"not"] compareOp
//ok
CompareOperator returns CompareOperator:
    (negated?='!' | negated?='not')? operator=CompareOp;

//compareOp ::= "=" | "in" | "<" | ">" | "=<" | ">="
enum CompareOp returns CompareOp:
                equal = '=' | inclusion = 'in' | lesser = '<' | greater = '>' | lesserOrEq = '<=' | greaterOrEq = '>=';

//arrowOp ::= ["some"|"one"|"lone"|"set"] "->" ["some"|"one"|"lone"|"set"]
//ok
ArrowOperator returns ArrowOperator:
    {ArrowOperator}
    (leftQuantifier=ArrowQuantifier)? '->' (=>rightQuantifier=ArrowQuantifier)?;

//"some"|"one"|"lone"|"set"
//ok
enum ArrowQuantifier returns ArrowQuantifier:
                lone = 'lone' | one = 'one' | some = 'some' | set = 'set' ; 

//19)       | "{" decl,+ blockOrBar "}" 
//ok
CurlyBracketsExpression returns CurlyBracketsExpression:
    '{' varDeclarations+=VarDeclaration ( "," varDeclarations+=VarDeclaration)* blockOrBar=BlockOrBar '}';

//blockOrBar ::= block
//blockOrBar ::= "|" expr
//ok
BlockOrBar returns BlockOrBar:
    BlockExpr | Bar;    

//blockOrBar ::= "|" expr
//ok
Bar returns Bar:
    '|' expression=Expression;

//block ::= "{" expr* "}"
//ok
BlockExpr returns BlockExpr:
    {BlockExpr}
    '{' (expressions+=Expression ( "," expressions+=Expression)*)?'}';

//3)         unOp expr
//         | finalExpression    
TerminalExpression returns TerminalExpression:
    UnaryExpr | finalExpression ;   

//3)         unOp expr
//ok
UnaryExpr returns UnaryExpr:
    unOp=UnaryOperator expression=TerminalExpression;

//unOp ::= "!" | "not" | "no" | "some" | "lone" | "one" | "set" | "seq" | "#" | "~" | "*" | "^"
//unOp ::= "!" | "not" |"#" | "~" | "*" | "^"
//ok
enum UnaryOperator returns UnaryOperator:
                not = 'not' | card = '#' | transpose = '~' | reflexiveClosure = '*' | closure = '^' | not2 = '!';


//16)       | "(" expr ")"
//9)        |     number
//10)       | "-" number
//17)       | ["@"] Name
//11)       | "none"
//12)       | "iden"
//13)       | "univ"
//14)       | "Int"
//15)       | "seq/Int"

//16)       | "(" expr ")"
//10)       | ["-"] number
//17)       | "@" Name
//17)       | reference
//12)13)    | constante
finalExpression returns TerminalExpression: 
    BracketExpression | NumberExpression | NotExpandedExpression | ReferenceExpression | ConstantExpression;    

//16)       | "(" expr ")"
//ok    
BracketExpression returns BracketExpression:
    '('expression=Expression')';

//9)        |     number
//10)       | "-" number
//ok    
Number returns Number:
    NumberExpression;

//ok
NumberExpression returns NumberExpression:
    value=EInt;

//17)       | ["@"] Name
//17)       | "@" Name
//ok
NotExpandedExpression returns NotExpandedExpression:
    '@' name=[IDref];

//ok
ReferenceExpression returns ReferenceExpression:
    reference=Reference;

//ref ::= name | "univ" | "Int" | "seq/Int"
//ok
Reference returns Reference:
    ReferenceName | ConstanteReference;

//ok
ConstanteReference returns ConstanteReference:
    cst=constanteRef;

//13)       | "univ"
//14)       | "Int"
//15)       | "seq/Int"
//ok
enum constanteRef returns constanteRef:
                int = 'Int' | seqint = 'seq/Int' | univ = 'univ';

//ok
ReferenceName returns ReferenceName:
    name=IDref;

//ok
ConstantExpression returns ConstantExpression:
    constante=Constant;

//11)       | "none"
//12)       | "iden"
//ok
enum Constant returns Constant:
                none = 'none' | iden = 'iden';


//ok    
Block returns Block:
    BlockExpr;

//letDecl ::= name "=" expr
//ok
LetDeclaration returns LetDeclaration:
    varName=VarDecl '=' expression=Expression;

//quant ::= "all" | "no" | "some" | "lone" | "one" | "sum"
//quant ::= "all" | "no" | "some" | "lone" | "one" | "null"
//ok
enum QuantifiedExpressionQuantifier returns QuantifiedExpressionQuantifier:
                no = 'no' | one = 'one' | lone = 'lone' | some = 'some' | all = 'all' | null = 'null';

//decl ::= ["private"] ["disj"] name,+ ":" ["disj"] expr
//ok
VarDeclaration returns VarDeclaration:
    (isPrivate?='private')? (varsAreDisjoint?='disj')? names+=VarDecl ( "," names+=VarDecl)* ':' (expressionIsDisjoint?='disj')? expression=Expression;


//scope ::= "for" number                   ["expect" (0|1)]
//scope ::= "for" number "but" typescope,+ ["expect" (0|1)]
//scope ::= "for"              typescope,+ ["expect" (0|1)]
//scope ::=                                ["expect" (0|1)]
//
//scope ::= "for" [number] ["but"] typescope,* 
//ok
Scope returns Scope:
    {Scope}
    'for' (number=Number)? (but?='but')? (typeScope+=TypeScope ( "," typeScope+=TypeScope)*)?;

//typescope ::= ["exactly"] number [name|"int"|"seq"]
//typescope ::= ExactlyNumber target
TypeScope returns TypeScope:
    num=ExactlyNums target=[TypeScopeTarget];


//[name|"int"|"seq"]
//[Validname|"int"|"seq"]
//ok
TypeScopeTarget_Impl returns TypeScopeTarget:
    {TypeScopeTarget}
    ;

Int0 returns Int:
    {Int}
    'Int'
    ;

Seq returns Seq:
    {Seq}
    'Seq'
    ;
```

But at runtime of the editor, I have the following error on the little exemple :

```
sig A {}
sig B {
    a : A
}

Multiple markers at this line (line a : A)
- no viable alternative at input 'A'
- missing EOF at '->'
- missing '}' at 'a'
```

the rule works for the first one, but not the second one. It is at is  expect there is no relationDeclartion between the brackets.
I think it is due to the declaration of the rule relationDeclaration call with the form :

```
(relations+=RelationDeclaration ( ',' relations+=RelationDeclaration)*)?
```

I cannot get what is wrong.
What did I miss?
What can I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more of your grammar. E.g. what does VarDecl and Expression look like?

It is always a good strategy to trim down a case to a minimal fully reproducable example. Often you figure out the problem yourself by doing that. If not it will be easier for others to figure it out afterwards.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for looking, I added details in the grammar. In the first version I tried to keep it simple for more understanding.

Comment: the grammar is still not complete. the interesting part is: by which expression shall the 'A' after the ':' be parsed? ReferenceExpression?

Comment: I forgot this rule, I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your grammar for `RelationDeclaration` it seems you miss some optional marking questionmarks `(isPrivate?='private')? (varsAreDisjoint?='disj')?` (the same problem is all over the grammar)

`?=` declares the attribute as optional, but only a `?` around the rule call makes it actually optional

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. In my model isPrivate is a boolean, writing     isPrivate?='private' should test if the 'private' keyword is writen, doesn't it?
I tried with the (isPrivate?='private')? (varsAreDisjoint?='disj')? in the rule relationDeclaration and the problem persist, should I try in the whole grammar?

PS: The same goes for the varsAreDisjoint keyword.

Comment: no from a grammar perspective ```isPrivate?='private'``` is the same as ```'private'``` so it is not optional. a usecase for that is ```(flag?='true' | 'false')```. so if you do not have alternatives or mark it as optional it is required and the flag will always be true. And you have to use the same pattern at all places where you have this flag (your grammar is not complete so i cannot give it a try)

Comment: I have added the full grammar with the modifications you had suggested. I have try it but the same goes on.

Comment: your grammar does not generate (it is left recursive)

Comment: Oops I forgot to generate when I tried. I corrected the grammar to avoid left recursivity, and now my problem is solved, thanks to you. I put the correction in the grammar above, there are still some errors but I think I can handle it, thank you.